# Javascript for-loop returning "null" instead of my value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to get the function below to return the average of all elements in `array1`, but I keep getting `null` as the result. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
var array1 = [46,73,-18,0,-442,779,5,1400];

var arrayAverage = function(arrayavg) {
    for (var average = 0,answer=0, arrayavg = arrayavg.length;array1 > answer;answer++)
        average +=parseInt(arrayavg[answer]);

    var calc = average/arrayavg.length;
    return calc
};
```

Comment: WOW! That is a complex for statement for what it is supposed to do! Why don't you just loop through the array, add values together and divide by length? Why do you need variables like answer, arrayavg etc.?

Comment: What do you expect the outcome of `array1 > answer` to be, given that *array1* is an Array and *answer* is a Number? What do you expect from `arrayavg[answer]` given that *arrayavg* is a Number (related code: `arrayavg = arrayavg.length`)?

Comment: I am not sure how you get `null` returned. How are you calling that?

Comment: Wow, these were some quick replys! @RaviH I'm trying to answer with the rounded integer. I wasnt sure I could do it any other way. I want the result to be 230.

Comment: @epascarello I'm using `arrayAverage(array1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a number to your array in your for loop. You want to stop the for when `answer` is the same as `array1` length.

Also, don't change your parameter array to its length if you want to get its values in the loop.

```
var array1 = [46,73,-18,0,-442,779,5,1400];

var arrayAverage = function(arrayavg) {
    for (var average = 0,answer=0, len = arrayavg.length;len > answer;answer++)
        average +=parseInt(arrayavg[answer]);
    var calc = average/len;
    return calc
};
```

And to call it:

```
arrayAverage(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need to put brackets after your for loop</strike>
I was too fast to answer.

You are re-assigning the passed array to the length of the passed array.

```
arrayavg = arrayavg.length
```

this breaks everything.

Comment: probably the simplest `{` solution

Comment: @forgivenson No, the indention is misleading. My answer was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of errors, I don't have time to point them all out, hopefully the following is sufficient:

```
var array1 = [46,73,-18,0,-442,779,5,1400];

var arrayAverage = function(arrayavg) {
```

I don't know why you using a function expression rather than a function declaration. It doesn't affect the issue, but is more code to write. It's also good to give variables names that express what they are for, so given that the function expects an array:

```
function arrayAverage(array) {
```

then:

```
  for (var average = 0,answer=0, arrayavg = arrayavg.length;array1 > answer;answer++)
```

It's not a good idea to pile all those variable declarations into the for condition, far better to separate concerns and only create variables that you need:

```
  var total = 0;
```

Now iterate over the array to get the total value. The '{' brackets can be omitted, but it's clearer to include them:

```
  for (var i=0, iLen=array.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    total += array[i];
  }
```

Now calculate the average and return it in one statement:

```
  return total/iLen;
}

console.log(arrayAverage(array1)); // 230.375
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Im still very new to Javascript which is why my code sometimes ends up like someone spilled juice on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the for loop  you have assigned `arrayavg=arrayavg.length` and in the body ,you are accessing `average+=arrayavg[answer]`. arrayavg is now a primitive type . it will return undefined.

And your loop condition is `array1 > answer` array1 is an array .you cant compare it like that.it will return false.

modified code.

```
var array1 = [46,73,-18,0,-442,779,5,1400];

var arrayAverage = function(arrayavg) {
var sum=0; 
for (var i=0;i<arrayavg.length;i++)
    sum +=parseInt(arrayavg[i]);
 return sum/arrayavg.length;
};
```

Comment: shorter approach                               `(array1.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;}))/array1.length)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems in the for loop.

```
for (var average = 0,answer=0, arrayavg = arrayavg.length;array1 > answer;answer++)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

First thing is you set `arrayavg` to arrayavg's length BUT in the next line you try to read the index of the array. Well you overwrote the array with a number! Not going to happen.

Second issue you are comparing an array 'array1' to a number 'answer' . What does that check do? Not what you think it is going. You want to be checking the length, but wouldn't you want to be checking the passed in array, not the hardcoded one?

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers (particularly RobG) have covered most of it. It might help to follow a couple of standard rules (that I use) for your loops:

1) Always have the index as the *first* declared element, the length of the array (for caching purposes) as the *second*, and *any other* variables after them.
2) Always use brackets to separate your loop code from the code in the rest of the function. That way you know when to return your averaged product (ie after the `}`).

So this is my slightly rewritten code of your problem:

```
for (var index = 0, len = arrayavg.length, avg = 0; index < len; index++) {
    avg += parseInt(arrayavg[index], 10) / len;
}
return avg;
```

Note also that `parseInt` should contain a radix (in this case 10). You can leave it out but it's good practice to always include it.

By the way, here's an alternative to your function you might find useful that uses a functional approach using `reduce`:

```
var arrayAverage = function (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) / arr.length;
}
```